# Embedded Server in Application

Tags: node.js, webserver

I have a software tool that I have recently upgraded. It is a fresh install and the upgraded product utilizes an Embedded Server. I have allowed the program through my AVG firewall and prior to that before I had AVG through Windows Firewall but still get the same errors. I have shut down the firewall and managed to load the product and get it to work. However this only happens once in every 10 or so attempts and after a reboot, followed by the closing of firewall off. I have attached the messages I get. The "Unable" message comes up first and if I try again the "Error" message comes up. 
I would appreciate any guidance or possible reasons you may know of why this is happening.
I have contacted the software producer with a ticket but they have only been able to make a couple of suggestions both of which I tried but failed to solve the problem. I have attached the two messages I get. [First Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jP4Q.jpg)

[Second Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2ufS.jpg)

Comment: What is your programming problem?

Comment: Hi there, It is not so much a programming problem than it is running the software. Quite simply when I run my programme (commercial package) I get the messages I attached above and can't run the programme. Occasionally it will open but parts of it run very slow.

Comment: Then it is off-topic here. It may or may not be on-topic on the Super User site.